# Db4o - refresh ALL new objects in persistent session

Tags: c#, db4o, object-oriented-database

is it possible in Db4o to load new objects into persistent IObjectContainer?

I have a desktop application which opens one connection (IObjectContainer) when started. if I query all objects with:

```
var objects = from DummyClass foo in session
              select foo
```

it selects all objects perfectly. However, if another client adds new classes after this, the same query still selects the same objects, without new ones.

I also know about:

```
session.Ext().Refresh(obj, int.MaxValue);
```

but I don't have even not activated references to new objects so there. **How to refresh new objects**?

Just note: I don't want to open/close session every time I need some data, I want to take advantage of OODB (Transparent activation, object persistance since loaded etc.)

Thank you

**UPDATE (code example for better understanding)**

```
// store one class to fill database with some data
using (var mainSession = SessionFactory.CreateNewConnection())
{
    mainSession.Store(new DummyClass());
    mainSession.Commit();
}

using (var mainSession = SessionFactory.CreateNewConnection())
{
    // returns one object
    var objects = from DummyClass foo in session
                 select foo;
    using (var secondSession = SessionFactory.CreateNewConnection())
    {
        secondSession.Store(new DummyClass());
        secondSession.Commit();
    }

    // this loop reload objects known for mainSession (which is not new object)
    foreach (var obj in objects2)
    {
        mainSession.Ext().Refresh(obj, int.MaxValue);
    }

    // new DummyClass is commited but still not visible (Read-Commited isolation)
    // returns one object
    var objects2 = from DummyClass foo in session
                  select foo;
}

using (var mainSession = SessionFactory.CreateNewConnection())
{
    // returns two objects
    var objects = from DummyClass foo in session
                 select foo;
}
```

I need something like:

```
// refresh all objects of DummyClass
session.Ext().Refresh(typeof(DummyClass), int.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **Commited** events:

```
using Db4objects.Db4o;
using Db4objects.Db4o.Events;
using Db4objects.Db4o.IO;
using Db4objects.Db4o.Ext;

namespace PushedUpdates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var config = Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration();
            config.File.Storage = new MemoryStorage();
            var container = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(config, "IN-MEMORY");

            var client = container.Ext().OpenSession();

            var clientEvents = EventRegistryFactory.ForObjectContainer(client);
            clientEvents.Committed += (s, a) =>
                                        {
                                            foreach(IObjectInfo added in a.Added)
                                            {
                                                System.Console.WriteLine(added.GetObject());
                                            }
                                        };

            container.Store(new Item { Value = 1 } );
            container.Commit();
            container.Store(new Item { Value = 2 });
            container.Commit();
            container.Store(new Item { Value = 3 });
            container.Commit();

            client.Close();
            container.Close();
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "" + Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for hint, but I am worrying about performance. This event is raised for each commit on all clients

Answer (score 1):

Did your client call the commit() method after storing the data? Otherwise the new data will not be available for other clients.